# Function $f(x)$ with roots at $k\pi$, $k\pi \omega$ and $k\pi\omega^2$ where $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, trigonometry, examples-counterexamples

I need to find a real valued function $f(x)$ with roots at $k\pi$, $k\pi \omega$ and $k\pi\omega^2$ where $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\omega$ is the cube root of unity.

I tried using the function $$f(x)=\sin x\sin(x/\omega)\sin(x/\omega^2)$$

But this function has roots at $n\pi$, $n\pi \omega$ and $n\pi\omega^2$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

I need your guidance. Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you simply restrict the domain?

Comment: @LanierFreeman Thank you. How can we do that rigorously?

Comment: Are you sure you need a real valued function? Also, does it have to be regular in some way, e.g. differentiable or holomorphic?

Comment: Or directly: either $f(x)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^3}{k^3\pi^3}\right)$ if your $\mathbb N$ is $\{1,2,\dots\}$, or the same multiplied by $x$ if  your $\mathbb N$ is $\{0,1,2,\dots\}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks. But is there a closed form for this product?

Comment: @Adayahi It can be holomorphic or differentiable.

Comment: Yes there is a closed form for the product. Hint: $\Gamma(z) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left((1+\frac z n)(1+\frac1n)^{-z}\right)$

Comment: Rather $1/\Gamma(z) =z\prod\dots$ But I can't see how it helps. @ 
DarkMalthorp. Btw, what is the standard convention (if any) for you english-speakers ($0\in\mathbb N$ or not?)

Comment: ... and if $k \in \mathbb N$, does the title mean that there should be a triple root at $0$?

Comment: @GEdgar No it means that we have a single root at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Worked out from the comments:
$$
\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^3}{k^3\pi^3}\right) =
{-\frac {{\pi}^{3}}{{x}^{3} \Gamma\left(  -{\frac {x}{\pi}}
 \right)    \Gamma \left( -{\frac {\omega\,x}{\pi}}
 \right)   \Gamma \left( -{\frac {{\omega}^{2}x}{
\pi}} \right) }} 
$$

Comment: Thanks. Can you please show a bit that how you ended with the quotient on the RHS?